# Splitting string in Python without breaking words

Tags: python, string

I want to split a string without breaking any words in the string.  After reading in a text file called "output.txt.", when I use the splitlines() function as below, it breaks the words at the line boundaries (for example, it breaks the word "from" and keeps "fr" on a first line, moving "om" to the next line.

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as file:
    temp = file.read()
x = ' '.join(temp.splitlines())
```

I am new to Python; using Python 3.6.8.  Is there a way to modify the splitlines() such that it breaks the string at line boundaries and returns a list of splitted strings, but it does not break words in the original string?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a copy-paste of the file's existing text?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I can't include the file's existing text because it's for a project that has private data (not shareable).  But even if I use a fictitious txt file, the above piece of code still splits the words.

Comment: So add **that** text here. any [mre] will do...

Comment: That code doesn't split words. They're split in the file already.

Comment: Thanks for your replies and patience everyone, I am new at this.  Some words (that would have been at the 'end of the line' based on splitting) do look split in the output of the code in my Jupyter notebook.  I just realized it could be just a matter of how JN wraps/does not wrap text in its display, but the purpose of my splitting the original string is to create a wordcloud, and in the wordcloud some broken words do show up too.  For example, "mak", which is part of make.  There is not "mak" in the original text, so it must have been the result of incorrect "splitting".

Comment: May I ask why the "-4" for my question?  Do people not ask "beginner" questions on this forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the awnser you're looking for, but you can use the .split() function on a string and give a parameter to split on. So if you have:
"Hello this is a string"
and you call .split(" ") on it, it returns: 
["Hello", "this", "is", "a", "string"]